# QTP: How to identify a object which was created while the script was running?

Tags: testing, vbscript, qtp

Now I am testing a online shop website with QTP.

The occured problem is quite tricky.
I already have an account, so I order a product, It will automatically show up my billing address.

What I need to test is that if I were to change this address, this address should be added in "my address"I can set the typed address in a variable. like (newaddress= "Sk ks, ....")
But the problem is I could not identify the created object. Because it was created during the script was running. Has anybody got an idea?

[image]

myQTP script to find the "SK ks ... " SPAN.

```
Set mypage = Browser("Browser").Page("Micasa")

If mypage.webelement("html tag:=span").Exist(3) Then       'or even class:=headline
    msgbox "it exists"
Else
    msgbox "doesn't exist"
    End if
End if
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard for me to understand what exactly the problem is, but let me try to help you.

Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the part that gives you trouble? After placing a breakpoint, you can run your script and it automatically breaks on the point of the breakpoint.
From there, you can use the GUI spy and the Object Repository (I assume you use the O.R. and do not use Descriptive Programming?) to detect the object to make the description in the O.R. more generic.

Comment: right. I use O.R.
While running the script, it opens the Component in read-only Mode, so I can just identify the object but can't add a new line.
For that, I stopped the script, and open the component again and identified the object by using adding new Object into O.R.
But the next time I run the script, it shows me the old object I selected (eg:- andereName.. ), but not the one I created recently (Sk ks..)

Comment: It looks like you are recognizing the component on it's 'value' property (or such-alike). The first time the value of this property is 'andereName', the second time 'Sk ks'. You need to change/add the Description properties to a more generic one. On a well constructed webpage it would be 'html id' as unique identifier, if it was lazy developped, you don't have a unique identifier and have to recognize it on 'tag name', 'class' and eventually ordinal identifier.

Comment: well the 'tag name' is SPAN and class is "webelement".
but both objects have the same values except the inner Text.

In the Ordinal Identifier I see the type, Value "sk ks.." got "Index 0", and the second object got "Index, 1".
How can use this difference in my script?

Comment: If you have an object with no unique identifier and a shifting Ordinal Id, you have a challenge. Some strategies: 1. Predict what the Ordinal Id will be, create an object for it in the OR and check that object. 2. Try to capture the parent object (probably a DIV) and get the innertext. Somewhere "Vorname:{your text}" must be stated. 3. Get the parent object and loop through its ChildCollection until you find your object. 4. through DP: Get the object with innertext:="Vorname", get the parent and get the sibbling after the object with Vorname. The latter ones are more difficult to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying as you said.
But I encountered problem there. If I search for an element with the name, it finds. But with the class name or html tag, it doesn't find.
My VB script is at the bottom of my post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534989/vb-script-how-to-find-whether-a-div-tag-contains-specified-text

my question is posted there. If you'd know, could you please post your code there. Thank you very much.

Comment: What you did was correct there, but if there is more then one object of type "webelement" with "html tag:=span", then you have to assign an ordinal identifier: `mypage.webelement("html tag:=span", "index:=0").Exist(3)` should work. But now, it takes the first span and that is probably not the one you are looking for. By adding more identifiers you can get to a better description. But look also into your other post, Motti has hinted you in the right direction there.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem identifying objects that were created during the test run. If QTP doesn't find an object it waits a bit and tries again. Your problem seems to be finding a good description for the `WebElement` you're looking for.

Looking at the comments on AutomatedChaos's answer it seems that you have a very minimal description (only the `html tag`). If this is really all you know about your `WebElement` you can use **Visual Relations Identifiers** (using QTP11) to find your element.