# VB Script: how to find whether a DIV tag contains specified text

Tags: html, vbscript, qtp

```
myaddress= "Sk ks, Röntenstrasse 31, Wolle"
```

I am writing VB script in QTP.
how can I find out whether if any DIV tag contains this "myaddress"?

```
if it exists
msgbox "it exists"
if not
msgbox "it doesn't".
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You need to use .object properties of page & then use GetElementBy HtmlId("Div").go for then with collection of obect with for loop & check innertext of object

Answer (score 1):

Using QTP you can use the `innertext` property to find an element.

```
 If Browser("bb").Page("pp").WebElement("html tag:=div", "innertext:=" & myaddress).Exist
    ' Treat element
 End If
```

BTW, if `myaddress` is just part of the inner text you should anchor it with wild cards on both sides:

```
"innertext:=.*" & myaddress & ".*"
```

Comment: Correct, but `"inner text"` should be `"innertext"` to work correctly.